# Is there any webservice to login to Liferay

Tags: liferay

Is there any webservice to login to Liferay. Can pass user name and password.

I checked here - host/api/jsonws but unable to find that kind of API.

Comment: Use any api you want, with Basic Auth header for authentication

Answer (score 2):

The result of a login action on a web application is that the session of the current user is populated with appropriate user-related information.

The purpose of a webservice is that some action is executed in the backend, typically isolated.

A webservice is meant to be populated by some program code, where you can't rely on "a cookie to be set", while this is the mechanism that an application uses, because the browser will honor such a cookie. Your API-client might not.

You can just look at the target of the login form to authenticate to Liferay: It's submitted through http(s), and you can do that through an API as well as through a browser.

For subsequent API access, I'd recommend you look into Liferay's OAuth features: That exists as well, and you'll be happier with the relatively new "headless" features than with the legacy jsonws-api. Or use Basic Authentication, as Daniele suggests in his comment.